# Sending an email to the conference asking for acceleration in review process

Tags: conference

I've recently sent an article to a conference which is supposed to send the review result by June 1. I'm supposed to participate in an interview in which the acceptance result of my paper in this conference will have a good impact on the result of the interview.

I want to know is it OK to send an email to this conference and ask them to respond earlier (for example 1 week earlier)? If so, what is the best way to express my request? Will it have a negative impact on the result of the review?

Comment: Realistically, as someone who hires fresh PhDs, the impact of one conference paper acceptance is not much at all. Focus on being able to portray yourself well in the interview.

Comment: Rely on your other papers etc and don’t waste the committees time asking for an early decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably not a reasonable request. You can ask, but I doubt it will make a difference.

Firstly, the program committee is already working to make decisions as quickly as possible. If they could expedite the process, they would. But there are constraints on the time of reviewers.

The thing you need to note is the conferences typically make decisions for all papers together. It is generally not the case that papers are decided on one by one. Thus they cannot expedite your decision ahead of other papers. (And if they could, why would they?) This may simply be because they have a fixed number of papers that they can accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask, of course. It is almost never wrong to ask. But I doubt that the conference committee will have any way to accommodate you. The one thing they could do is do a quick analysis and reject if they thought it was an especially poor paper. Don't fear that they would do that for the wrong reasons, but it would give you a quick answer. You might also get encouragement from a quick look, but almost certainly not quick acceptance.

The problem is that the committee has little control over the reviewers and their schedules.

Again, it isn't that your review would be prejudiced, but just that it is easier, in most cases, to recognize an inappropriate paper than a good one. The good ones are usually discussed in committee while the schedule is being filled out and there are more "acceptable" papers than will fit the schedule.